# Pre/Post Increment operator expression Java

Tags: java

In Java

```java
int a=10;
a = a + ++a;
System.out.println(a);
```

it prints `21`. I had understood that it would print `22`

I had understood that since '++' has higher precedence, so it will be calculated first and it will change a's value as it is pre-increment, so increment to variable 'a' would happen there and then...later it should add with a's latest value

like below:

```java
a = a + 11; // (a is 11 after pre - increment)
```

so, now `a = 11 + 11 = 22`, but program produces `o/p = 21`.

means it is not picking a's latest value which is `11`, and using the old value which was `10`

```java
a = 10+ 11 = 21
```

..
can someone please clear my doubt?

would appreciate it if the answer contains the concept/reference from any book or java specification

Comment: You need to understand how you statement is being executed,
Its Executed from left to right.
So for Instance -> a = 10 + 11 = 21

Comment: @Vivek Swansi is right. When you add a = ++a +a you get 11 +11 = 22

Answer (score 2):

- `i++` - get and then increment
- `++i` - increment and then get
- `unary operations (++, !)` have **the highest** priority
- expression is evaluated from [Left to Right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1) (thanks to [user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675))

```java
int i = 10;
System.out.println(i++);  // 10
System.out.println(i);    // 11
System.out.println(++i);  // 12
System.out.println(i);    // 12
```

In your example:

```java
int a = 10;
a = a + ++a; // -> 10 + (10 + 1), from left to right
System.out.println(a);  // 21
```

Answer (score 2):

From Java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated
> from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Since a =10, a = 10 + 11 = 21.

Why? Because the value of a is 10, Because You Didn't Increment it yet, it stays at 10.

in ++a, now only you incremented it, then becomes 11.
now , a = 10 + 11 is 21.